# Using Azure DevOps connected to github, how do I set up an automated build that happens whenever changes are made to the master branch?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I'm thoroughly confused as to how ADO pipelines work - all I want to do is generate a build which is publicly accessible whenever a changeset or pull request is applied to the master branch in github. Can someone please walk me through the process of setting up this pipeline? I feel like it's got to be really simple but it just doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: Hi there, did the solution below fix your issue? If so, please mark as answer. If not, let us know any new information to help further

Comment: I think so, but I have yet to push any changes to this repo since I made the change to the build configuration, so I'm not 100% sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

The UI in this link is a bit outdated but the actual steps are the same. You can probably skip to "Exercise 2: Configure Build" if your connection to Git is already set up. https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/github/

Then make sure your trigger is configured correctly [image: Build Trigger]

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this through UI or yaml? Have you walk through this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2)?

Comment: I'm trying to use the UI for now. The guide you linked doesn't really say much about what I'm trying to do. Did you mean to post your answer as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with yaml:

1.new a build pipeline --> choose GitHub(YAML) --> Select a repository --> Complete configuration

[image]

2.Use the below syntax in yaml file

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
```

For the details ,please refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).